# Entity Framework 6: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework-6

I'm creating WPF application using Entity Framework 6 with database first approach. EF did everything for me and i'm able to connect to the database and so far downloading data works, so connection exists. But every time i add user control it gives me new error that connection string was not detected. Program works fine anyway, but its hard to program when your error window is flooded with it.

I have found out that changing context from:

```cs
public MediaRentalEntities()
     : base("name=MediaRentalEntities")
{
}
```

To this:

```
public MediaRentalEntities()
     : base("MediaRentalEntities")
{
}
```

Should fix the issue, but it doesn't. 
Now it throws exception (and shows this error multiple times, based how many user controls i have, currently 3):

*The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715*

This is my current app.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MediaRentalEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;data source=localhost;initial catalog=MediaRental;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

It's starting to be tiring, i'm tempted to change to EntityFrameworkCore or even Dapper, it feels like EntityFramework6 is against the user, but WPF has way more functionality on .NET Framework.

Comment: in connection string replace  MyModel with "MediaRentalEntities" .It will work

Comment: @VishalPawar System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Unable to load the specified metadata resource.'

Comment: Ok it was issue while copying, it was MediaRentalEntities and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

in connection string replace  **MyModel** with "**MediaRentalEntities**" .It will work

Or

If you have generated it using DB first then you will already have context class where code is like

```
 public MyModel()
     : base("name=MyModel")
{
}
```

Comment: Issue while copying, it was MediaRentalEntities. As i said above both constructors don't work.

Comment: You probably mess the code which was autogenerated. unto your changes till model was autogenerated in db first.

Comment: When its auto generated i have the error that connection string was not detected (program works fine, its just annoying to work with error list flooded). Internet suggests messing and it gets worse. But either way there are errors that i would like to fix. Otherwise i will be forced to change to EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: I will recommend you, do it from scratch and not touch the connections string and context class. they are mapped internally. All the best

Comment: So EntityFrameworkCore it is. Or i will just live with error list flooded.

Comment: create new application .

Comment: I doubt it will work but i will try. I also have a theory that UserControl can't access it, since error appears only when UserControls are added.

Comment: @Vishal_Pawar created new project, same issue. I can't believe not a single person can solve it. Or just no one uses EF6.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213353/discussion-between-sergeantcat-and-vishal-pawar).